# Passing a member function as callback to another class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to pass the member function of one class as a callback to another class. But when this other class tries to call the callback, I get the following error:

> TypeError: this.dataUpdateCallback is not a function

Here's the full code:

```
// Class A
module.exports = function MyTestClass() {

    // Member variables
    this.service = null;

    // Starts the service
    this.start = function() {
        this.service = new MyCoolService(this.processNewData);
        this.service.start();
    }

    // Processes incoming data
    this.processNewData = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}

// Class B
module.exports = function MyCoolService(aDataUpdateCallback) {

    // Member variables
    this.dataUpdateCallback = aDataUpdateCallback;

    // Starts the service
    this.start = function() {
        // Do stuff, then call...
        this.dataUpdateCallback("Hello World!"); // => TypeError: this.dataUpdateCallback is not a function
    }
}
```

PS: I don't think the mentioned duplicate helps here. The problem seems to be a little different...
As far as I understood, I would have to save the this of class A somewhere in class B, so that when calling class A I can use the correct one. But class B never gets to see a this, so there is nothing I could store.

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. It seems to be the solution for a different problem...

Comment: If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please [edit] it to **explain what makes it unique**. You already seem to know that it is unique - you just need to explain why that is.

Comment: Well, the solution presented for the other question simply does not work here. Or at least I don't see how it can be applied to my problem. But I'll try to edit my question.

Comment: Could you please un-mark this as a duplicate? Thanks!